# Rheem ac and furnace as one unit model RRGG- 07E24 JKR

Tags: furnace

I have the C wire, 5 wires total. Trying to find where to hook up the C wire in the furnace. This furnace does not have a board with the wiring like most do, the 4 wires are connected, the c wire, no place to connect it to the furnace. If I just ground it to the furnace will that work? Or does it have to be connected on the 24 V side for the c wires?

[image]
<sup>Click images to embiggen</sup>

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of your unit's wiring diagram please?

Comment: no wiring diagrams did fine the transformer TB402424 B2 1A PRI RD BC3K B10COM 208 240 SEC YU 24U -22 LOOKS LIKE THE YELLOW WIRES ARE THE 24 VOLTS BOTH ARE YELLOW CAN I CONNEECT THE BLUE WIRE TO ONE OF THEM?

Comment: Might want to redo that comment, or even better, put it into the question itself. Not sure exactly what all that means and you left shout-case on.

Comment: the 16 volts  i get on the c wire will not power the thermostat takes 28 to 30 volts

Comment: Loads of pictures. None of them show anything in enough detail to be useful. Can't read the labels on the terminal blocks. Some have a wire in the way, blocking the view. Please [edit] to provide better pics.

Answer (score 0):

With a volt meter set for AC volts measure between the RH/RC terminal and one of those yellow transformer wires. If you measure something around 24 volts (22-30 volts might be expected) then the yellow wire you're measuring against is the C. If you measure something different, try measuring against the other yellow transformer wire.

Comment: Hi thank you for your time, i did do that, i got 28 votes but after hooking the c wire to the yellow transformer wire. I checked it again on the wall were the thermostat is. here is what  i get, RC TO W G Y  28-volt but the c wire  is blue, only get 16 votes tried it on both sides of the yellow wires of the transformer dead one of them, the other were the red wire coming from the thermostat and too a switch, i get 28 volts. that is checking it from outside not from the wall  if you check it from the wall only 16 volts

Comment: Honeywell thermostat, Wi-Fi and boy is it a honey  i shorted the transformer out now checked bad, so will try to fine one, show it in the pictures looks like it is a 120 208 ar e 230 down to 28 voltes can.t make it out very well the furnace is on 220